# Session gets expired on some pages - asp.net

Tags: asp.net, session

We recently moved one of our applications to a new server. Earlier both the Web and DB were on the same server. Now they are on seperate servers on the same network. After this move, the session gets expired on some pages. This is really strange behaviour, and I have been unable to find a solution so far.

below are the event log details.

```
Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event time: 14/06/2017 16:26:50 
Event time (UTC): 14/06/2017 10:56:50 
Event ID: fc97896890a049098441b1c00e76637a 
Event sequence: 3 
Event occurrence: 1 
Event detail code: 0 

Application information: 
Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/OrangeTemp-1-131419114095107559 
Trust level: Full 
Application Virtual Path: /OrangeTemp 
Application Path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\OrangeTemp\ 
Machine name: ORA-SFAAPPSRV 

Process information: 
Process ID: 5148 
Process name: w3wp.exe 
Account name: IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool 

Exception information: 
Exception type: NullReferenceException 
Exception message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at Zamsana.Vantage.WebUI.HOReturns.FirstPageLoad()
at Zamsana.Vantage.WebUI.FrontLogic.BasePage.Page_Load(Object sender, 
EventArgs e)
at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean 
includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Request information: 
Request URL: http://localhost/OrangeTemp/HOReturns.aspx 
Request path: /OrangeTemp/HOReturns.aspx 
User host address: ::1 
User: kasunc 
Is authenticated: True 
Authentication Type: Forms 
Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool 

Thread information: 
Thread ID: 6 
Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool 
Is impersonating: False 
Stack trace:    at Zamsana.Vantage.WebUI.HOReturns.FirstPageLoad() at 
Zamsana.Vantage.WebUI.FrontLogic.BasePage.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs 
e)
at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean 
includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: All I see is a `NullReferenceException`. Not code containing a Session.